# Error handling in co-dependent observables

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable, bluetooth-lowenergy

Update based on backtick's suggestions:

```
    this.ble.connect(macAddr)
    .pipe(
      tap(outer => console.log(`outer observable`)),
      switchMap(() =>
      this.ble.startNotification(macAddr, 
        ENV.CUSTOM_SERVICE,
        ENV.VALUE_CHARACTERISTIC)
          .pipe(
            tap(inner => console.log(`inner observable`)),
            timeout(3000) // <- no further messages
          )
      ),
      // timeout(3000), // <- errors after 18 seconds
      retry(5)
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(`incoming buffer: ${new Uint8Array(data).join(':')}`),
      (error) => console.log(`outer observable ${error}`)
    );
```

With the timeout in the inner observable the messages just stop with no further log.

```
10:03:45.269 outer observable
10:03:46.058 inner observable
10:03:46.059 incoming buffer: 8:0:138:255:0:0:0:0
```

With the timeout in the outer pipe it hits the main subscription's error block after 18 seconds. This would correspond to 5 retries of 3 second gaps plus one. Which suggests it's retrying the inner observable but not logging the tap in that pipe.

```
09:58:08.426 inner observable
09:58:08.426 incoming buffer: 48:0:138:255:0:0:0:0
09:58:26.516 outer observable handling final TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred
```

The desired behaviour is for it to retry the connection on errors from either observable and resubscribe to the notification characteristic.

Note: The async was present as I have to use a promise to set a mode on the device after initial connection and prior to notification subscription. Omitted for simplicity.

```
await this.ble.write(macAddress, ENV.CUSTOM_SERVICE,
                        ENV.MODE_CHARACTERISTIC, mode);
```

I've been swapping in and out variations of retryWhen/switchMap/mergeMap/concatMaps and this is as close as I can get to a working solution.

```
this.ble.connect(macAddress)
    .pipe(
      retry(5),
      switchMap(async (value, index) => {
        console.log(`in higher order mapping ${index}`);

        return this.ble.startNotification(macAddress, 
                                          ENV.CUSTOM_SERVICE,
                                          ENV.VALUE_CHARACTERISTIC);
          .pipe(
            timeout(BLE_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT),
          ).subscribe(
            result => 
              console.log(`incoming buffer: ${new Uint8Array(result).join(':')}`),
            error => {
              console.log(`listening for notifications`, error);
              return throwError(error);
            }
          );
      })
    )
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(`'next' block of outer observable`, data)
    , error => console.log(`outer observable handling final ${error}`)
)
```

When the app connects to the BLE device it subscribes to a characteristic with a Notify property. Errors can occur in either the connection or the notification observables. In the first case it's clean enough, the connection is reestablished and the notification subscribed to. In the latter case, unless the connection breaks, the error isn't surfaced to the outer observable and a retry doesn't occur. I'm not sure what way I should be combining these two observables but if there is an error in either one of them I'd like to retry the connection, and restart the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues working against you:

**First**, the inner call to `subscribe` (within the `switchMap`) is non-idiomatic and will behave strangely.

As a concept, operators exist to abstract away `subscribe` as a mechanism for transforming/controlling observables. Thus, directly subscribing to observables *within* an operator's callback is counter to the notion of operators, which are functions that accept an observable and return a new one. Removing the call to subscribe is all you need to do here - subscription of inner observables will be handled automatically when you call subscribe on the entire construction.

**Second**, the placement of the `retry` operator means retries will only be initiated based on errors thrown from the connection observable. It will need to be placed after the `switchMap` if you want to catch notification errors as well.

**Third**, your `switchMap` callback is declared to be `async` which, even in the absence of the `await` keyword, wraps the callback's return value in a Promise. This is likely not what you want to do if the callback's return value is already an observable (or [observable-like](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/type-alias/ObservableInput)).

**Lastly** (though this was likely introduced inadvertently in your pasting of the example), there is a semicolon preceding the `.pipe()` call in the `switchMap` callback, which would cause a syntax error.

This is likely the construction you want.

```js
this.ble
  .connect(macAddress)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      this.ble
        .startNotification(
          macAddress,
          ENV.CUSTOM_SERVICE,
          ENV.VALUE_CHARACTERISTIC
        )
        .pipe(timeout(BLE_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT))
    ),
    retry(5) // Capture failures of connection *or* notification timeout
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data) => console.log(`'next' block of outer observable`, data),
    (error) => console.log(`outer observable handling final ${error}`)
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I've updated the question in place. I still can't get the outer observable to retry the connection when the inner observable times out.

Comment: It looks like the inner observable is emitting once before the `timeout` cutoff, which is all it takes to avoid the timeout condition. If I understand correctly, your expectation is that the timer restarts after each value sent by the notification observable. That's possible to achieve as well, just not with `timeout`.

Comment: The inner observable emits lots before I drop the device it's listening to in a tube that blocks its bluetooth signal :) Oh, I see, if you provide a date it acts as you've described. If it receives a number it times out when the period between emissions is greater. BLE_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT is a number.